# How to save forms in django with foreign key

Tags: python, django

I'm making a to-do list app and I'm trying to make the create page for an Item. Most of it works except that I don't get it to save in what Todo List to go and therefor get this error. 'Cannot assign "'Home'": "Item.todolist" must be a "TodoList" instance.'
This is my view:

```
def create_todo(request):
context = {"lists": TodoList.objects.filter(user=request.user)}

if request.method == "POST":
    if request.POST.get("create"):
        title = request.POST.get("item_title")
        date_due = request.POST.get("item_date")
        text = request.POST.get("item_note")
        todolist = request.POST.get("todolist")
        t = Item(
            user=request.user,
            todolist=todolist,
            title=title,
            date_due=date_due,
            text=text,
            complete=False,
        )
        t.save()
        redirect("all-todos-view")

return render(request, "create_todo.html", context)
```

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class TodoList(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("all-todos-view")


class Item(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     todolist = models.ForeignKey(TodoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     date_due = models.DateTimeField(
         auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True
     )
     text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
     complete = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("all-todos-view")
```

Comment: You first need to create an instance of todo-list `todolist = request.POST.get("todolist")` this part should be something like `todolist = TodoList(request.POST.get("todolist"), request.user).save()` assuming todolist thing contains the "name" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
t = Item( title=title,
          date_due=date_due,
          text=text,
          complete=False,
        )
        t.save(commit=False)
        t.user = request.user
        t.todolist.name = todolist
        t.save()
        return redirect("all-todos-view")
```